# EACH_QUORUM With Tolerance For Datacenter Loss

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am looking for some ideas on achieving a consistency of EACH_QUORUM on a 3 datacenter scenario, with a tolerance for 1 data center loss for writes.

Based on my understanding, EACH_QUORUM does not tolerate a data center loss. All my writes will fail as long as the data center is down. One option, is to retry the request with lower consistency level like 'QUORUM'.

Option I am looking for is, if there is a way to remove the failed DC and achieve EACH_QUORUM on remaining 2 live datacenters. From server side, only way I can think of is decommission all the nodes of failed datacenter, which is cumbersome.

Assuming that my client application knows that a datacenter is down, is there a way from Cassandra client driver to pass in a list of live datacenters, so the coordinator node tries to achieve EACH_QUORUM only on those datacenters.

Would appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Apache Cassandra for Disaster Recovery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647921/configuring-apache-cassandra-for-disaster-recovery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of a retry with local_quorum can be done by implementing a [RetryPolicy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/RetryPolicy.html) and apply it to the Session. Since the driver knows that it won't be able to achieve to achieve each_quorum, it won't actually try it, and you can handle the error in the retry policy instead of letting bubble up to your application code. I have tried this approach successfully.

Another idea I was considering was a separate Session for each DC (configured as the "local DC"), and execute asynchronously against each. Then depending on the error and what I can gather from the cluster state, log a warning or throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why using `EACH_QUORUM` if you're looking for an ability to survive DC failure? Use `LOCAL_QUORUM` then - it was designed for exactly that.